# Paging an XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to page an XML dataset in PHP.

The website I'm running is not high-volume so an implementation that would query the whole XML serialized file for each page is ok, but I'd be interested in hearing also approaches that *do it right* from the start (maybe slicing the file in many smaller files).

What are some approaches to do this in PHP?

Comment: High volume & large XML screams for `XMLReader` imho. Not the most user-friendly implementation, but very low memory & cpu usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal preference is [`simplexml_load_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) since it makes handeling XML so much more easier using [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) than using [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

- Define how many items are visible on a page
- Count all items in your dataset
- Select the actual offset from your dataset